# Send message to a target device

Tags: android, ios, mobile, push-notification, whatsapp

Is there a way to send message to a device other than push notification? I have to keep sending messages to devices even if its push notification is disabled. How does whatsapp work?

Many thanks

Savio

Comment: did you check https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging which works on doze and adaptive battery case also

Comment: may be use to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801835/how-to-implement-beluga-or-whatsapp-like-messaging-system-in-android-2-1?rq=1

Comment: "I have to keep sending messages to devices even if its push notification is disabled."
This statement violate user privacy and control AFAIK. If user decide to not to receive any notification, why you should force it? And the answer to "Is there a way to send message to a device other than push notification?" you can just send an SMS to your user.